# Air conditioner sockets and mobile phone charging

Tags: power

I want to know if/how my air conditioner and my phone charging works on the same power socket. i.e when I want to charge my phone I remove the air conditioner plug and use say my charger or my iron on the same socket. Is this OK? Any cause for worries? I have been doing this for a while now and everything seems fine. The power to my wall is 230 V a.c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason both low and high power devices work plugged into the same outlet is because the outlet provides a fixed *voltage*, not power.  Power is voltage times current, and each device draws only the current it needs.

Think about what is going on when nothing is plugged in.  The outlet is still providing 230 V in your case, but no current, and therefore no power.

The outlet maintains the voltage as long as you don't exceed some maximum current.  There is a circuit breaker in series with the outlet so that the outlet is shut down completely if you try to draw more current than the outlet can safely deliver.

You can therefore plug in as many or as few devices as you want, as long as the total current draw doesn't exceed the breaker trip point.

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem at all as long as all devices are rated for 230 volts and none of them exceed the current rating of the outlet ( which would trip a breaker or blow a fuse ). But typically an air conditioner is one of the heaviest loads so your other devices should not draw more current.